# html with many similar selects that react when changed

Tags: javascript, php, html

My html contains many similar selects which I thought I could do all as

```
<form name="form">
<select name="site" size="1" onChange="formHandler()">
  <option value="$site?i=$i&j=$2">ABC</option>
  ...
</select>
</form>
```

Contained in the html header is

```
function formHandler() {
  var URL = "";
  URL = document.form.site.options[document.form.site.selectedIndex].value;
  if ( (URL != "") && (URL != "0") ) {
    window.location.href = URL;
  }
}
```

But I get TypeError: document.form.site is undefined. I presume this is because the forms and their selects all have the same name. This is because I only want one formHandler() in the header.

Very thankful for help!

Comment: you are missing opening angle bracket on your closing option tag. Other than that the code is working fine. here is a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/s54xy1z8/

Comment: That was an editing mistake. Corrected it. Thanks for the fiddle. Yes, it works. Copy the the form to have two of them and it no longer works. That's my problem.

Comment: don't use name of the elements, send them as reference to the function. here is the updated fiddle (as Quagaar has answered) https://jsfiddle.net/s54xy1z8/2/

Answer (score 3):

Pass the element as parameter to the handler function:

```
onchange="formHandler(this)"
```

and then in the handler:

```
function formHandler(el) {
    var url = el.options[el.selectedIndex].value;
    // and the rest...
}
```